# Spring 4.1 JdbcTemplate Multiple ResultSet's

Tags: spring-4

I have a situation where I need to execute several queries within the same statement. I was doing this fine with Java, but now I'm trying to switch over to Spring and build a better application. Anyhow, I have something like this:

```
select * from table;select * from table2;
```

The code above is a sample and I'm not really querying 2 tables like that. The 3rd party application that I am using returns multiple record sets for faceted search and metadata on the index etc... Anyhow, with a standard Java class I am able to do the following:

```
        PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql).execute();

        do {
            ResultSet rs = ps.getResultSet();
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = md.getColumnCount();
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Map row = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
                for (int i=1; i <=columns; ++i) {
                    row.put(md.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
                    // append to our string builder the unique id for each record found
                    if(cnt == 1) {
                        if(md.getColumnName(i).equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
                            id_list.append(rs.getObject(i) + ",");
                        }
                        if(md.getColumnName(i).equalsIgnoreCase("part_number")){
                            suggest.append(rs.getObject(i) + "|");
                        }
                    }
                }
                list.add(row);
            }
            result.put(label, list);
        } while (ps.getMoreResults());
```

I trimmed this down for the sake of brevity but left enough code for a visual. I was able to run a single query with JdbcTemplate.query(sql,rowmapper) and was very impressed with the results.

If anyone can offer some guidance and tell me what would work I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would not utilize a multi-result SQL statement when using JDBCTemplates.  Instead, start a transaction and call template.query(...) multiple times for exactly what you are looking to retrieve.  You gain very little by trying to shove all your SQL into a single request to the database.

```
@Tranactional
public void retrieveStuff(List<Stuff> stuffList) {
  List<StuffResult> results = new ArrayList<StuffResult>(stuffList.size());
  for(Stuff stuff : stuffList) {
    results.add(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, getSQLParameters(stuff), StuffResult.class));
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: you could do union. select * from tab1 union select * from tab2. not sure if this works with your current database.

Comment: it's just how this particular search engine works, it returns multiple record sets and this is something out of my control. I have a class that returns the data into JSON format for me, but I was hoping to convert it to Spring for the cleaner and more maintainable approach.